# UIWebView not scaling to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a UICollectionView that contains UIWebviews in each cell. I've almost got it working but I am having this problem of not being able to resize the webviews to the cell's content size. Each webview size so far is 1024x704 (width x height) and is a html file. I have enabled `scalesPageToFit` to `YES` but all it's doing right now is resizing it to only fit in the upper left corner.

I've checked the frame size of the webview and the collectionviewcell size and i get 1024x704 programmatically even though what is actually appearing seems to be a lot smaller than that.

Any suggestions/help on why this is happening and what I can do to scale it correctly? If I need to supply more info let me know. Thanks

EDIT:
As shown below this is how the UICollectionView looks like on an iPad. The rectangle in the left is the UIWebView and I'm trying to scale it to fit the whole screen.

[image]

EDIT2: Just realized I screwed up on how I wrote my html file. Sorry about that guys! Problem solved itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
self.webView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
self.webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

Comment: Didn't work, I'm still getting the same layout from before. I'll try to post a picture to further show what I mean.

Comment: Try setting constraints on the webView.

Comment: Actually just realized that I didn't write my html file correctly. Whoops!! Thanks for your help though.